# How to find a song that I rated "thumbs up"

Tags: google-play-music

I recently started using Google Play Music and have rated a few songs so far. Now I'm looking for a track that I rated "thumbs up" but can't remember the artist or title.

I expected to find something in "recent activity", but there doesn't seem to exist a list of previously rated tracks anywhere...

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Google Play Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2851643?hl=en):

> You can give songs a thumbs up or thumbs down rating to let Google
>   Play know your preferences. When you give a song a thumbs up rating,
>   it appears in your [Thumbs up auto-playlist](https://play.google.com/music/listen#/ap/auto-playlist-thumbs-up). When you give a song
>   a thumbs down rating, you won't see recommendations for that song
>   anymore.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I wasn't able to find this playlist in the app, but maybe I was just being blind.

Comment: By the way, the link is also only available on the PC, clicking on it on my Android device, the Play Music opens to the home screen, but does not play the auto-playlist. Just in case anyone stumbles upon this issue.

Comment: The problem for me is that there's a playlist size limit of about 1000 songs. After many years using Google Music I surpassed that number with tracks that I've thumbed-up. Now I don't know how to obtain the complete list anymore...

Comment: You can also find this on desktop and mobile under `Music Library` > `Playlists` > `Auto-playlists` > `Thumbs up`.

Answer (score -1):

You can also find them in your thumbs up playlist on your phone. It will be grey if you don't own the song. I just thought about it and it worked for me this morning.